# Using XL Algorithm to solve overdetermined systems, simple example required

Tags: cryptanalysis, implementation, post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptography, algebraic-attack

Can someone give an example of how the XL algorithm is used to solve an overdetermined system as apposed to just a general case?

I have a fairly good understanding of how steps of the algorithm work, extending the system, then linearizing the system in the hopes of obtaining a univariate polynomial which is then solved. A small example with numbers and variables over a finite field would help me to see what's going on and understand the algorithm more.

Comment: To come up with such a system just choose $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ multivariate polynomials in $n$ variables with $n<m$, evaluate them at some point $\mathbf{a}$ to get $(c_1,\ldots,c_m)$, and then use the polynomials $(f_1-c_1,\ldots,f_m-c_m)$